# what is meaning of Request Sent in google chrome network tab?

Tags: api, google-chrome, http, networking

I am trying to debug why my apis call taking so much time. in google chrome network is showing Request Time is 8 min. what does tell mean like browser took 8 min to send request or it took 8 min to server to response first byte.[image]

Comment: What do you request ? Do you have that on a different PC ? Which BackEnd do you use ?

Comment: @JonathanDelean  i trying to upload some files around 3 MB  with post request.

Answer (score 0):

- Your clients have a slow connection, or someone is abusing their
  bandwidth.
- The data they are trying to access are very large.
- The server has slow upload speed.